# Is it bad practice to have a setTimeout on my loading state to prevent the log in page from flashing before the user is finished being authenticated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a React Native application and the only way I was able to get the login page to stop flashing before the user is authenticated was to add a setTimeout as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  const [IsReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const LoadFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={LoadFonts}
        onFinish={() =>
          setTimeout(() => {
            setIsReady(true);
          }, 1000)
        }
        onError={(error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  return <Providers />;
```

Is this bad practice? What is a better way to solve this? The reason why I had to do this is that in my Routes.js file I check if the user is authenticated and if they aren't they get the login stack navigation. If they are they get the home page.

Routes.js

```
export default function Routes() {
  const { user, setUser, setFirestoreUserData } = useContext(AuthUserContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (authUser) => {
      await (authUser ? setUser(authUser) : setUser(null));
    });

    return unsubscribeAuth;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const getUserObject = await getUserFromFirestore(user.uid);
      setFirestoreUserData(getUserObject);
    };
    if (user) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
      {user ? <TabStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how to refactor this, much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: set `IsReady` to `true` when the user is authenticated

Comment: @Bravo Are you referring to the onFinish function in AppLoading? What is the best way to do that? Any modifications I seem to make splash screen persist

Comment: I'm talking about where ever you determine that *user is authenticated* - I assume your code determines that, somewhere?

Comment: @Bravo I see, so I’m using the app loading in App.is and my data is being fetched by the useEffects I posted. Let me play around with this and see what the best way is to set it when user is done!

Comment: Try `setTimeout` of 0 if the is purely an issue of letting other async process to finish first. Otherwise it's the way you are desiging your component in relation to lifecycles.

Comment: @Dan I went ahead and tried 0 and 100 and got flashes still. 1000 was the sweet spot almost Edit: You're right, I may need to take some time to refactor the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This answer has been updated to use the newer Modular Firebase SDK (v9+). See the [older revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68871889/3) for the code for the legacy Namespaced Firebase SDK (v8 or older).

If you are unsure which to use, use the Modular Firebase SDK. The older version won't see any updates.

---

The flashes you experience are caused by your `Routes` component.

This is because when a user first loads your site, their authentication state is *pending*. Before the SDK says that a user is properly signed in, it must first phone home to the Firebase Authentication servers to check if that user session is valid. If you call `firebase.auth().currentUser` while this is still taking place, it will return `null`.

So because your `Routes` component includes these lines where user is coming from `firebase.auth().currentUser`:

```js
return (
  <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
    {user ? <TabStack /> : <AuthStack />}
  </NavigationContainer>
);
```

Your page renders `AuthStack` for a brief moment while `user` is `null`, before rerendering `TabStack` instead after confirming the user's session.

This will always occur regardless of what value you are using for `setTimeout` in `App` because it's not related to that but under your `Providers` component.

To correct this, you must return `null` from your `Routes` component while the auth session is confirmed.

As I'm not familiar with your `AuthUserContext` implementation, I'll be basing my answer on this one instead (which handles both the user's state and their primary user data).

```js
// ./FirebaseAuthUserContext.jsx
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { app } from './firebase.js' // should contain `export const app = initializeApp(...)`
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, doc, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

export const FirebaseAuthUserContext = createContext({
  // the current user's data
  data: undefined,
  // more information about the current user's data
  dataInfo: { status: "loading" },
  // the status of fetching the current user's data
  dataStatus: "loading",
  // the status of checking the user's auth session
  initializing: true,
  // the current user object
  user: undefined
});

export const useAuth = () => useContext(FirebaseAuthUserContext);

export function FirebaseAuthUserProvider({children}) {
  ​// If authentication state has been determined already,
 ​ // use the current user object. Otherwise, fall back to `undefined`.
 ​ const [user, setUser] = useState(() => getAuth(app).currentUser || undefined);
 ​ // If initial `user` value is `undefined`, we need to initialize.
 ​ const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(user === undefined);

  ​// Prep a space to hold their user data
  ​//  - data?:   user data object, as applicable
  ​//  - error?:  error related to the user's data, as applicable
  ​//  - ref?:    reference to user data's location, as applicable
  ​//  - status:  status of the user data
  ​const [userDataInfo, setUserDataInfo] = useState({ status: "loading" });

  ​useEffect(() => onAuthStateChanged(getAuth(app), (user) => {
    ​setUser(user); // user is User | null
    ​if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  ​}), []);

  ​useEffect(() => {
   ​ if (initializing) return; // do nothing, still loading auth state.

    ​if (user === null) {
      ​setUserDataInfo({ status: 'signed-out', data: null });
      ​return;
    ​}
    ​
    ​const userDataDocRef = doc(getFirestore(app), "users", user.uid);
 
    ​return onSnapshot( // <- returns an unsubscribe callback
      userDataDocRef,
      {
        ​next: (snapshot) => {
          if (snapshot.exists) {
            setUserDataInfo({
              status: "loaded",
              get data() { return snapshot.data() },
              ref: userDataDocRef
            });
          } else {
            setUserDataInfo({
          ​    status: "not-found",
              data: null,
              ref: userDataDocRef
            ​})
          }
        },
        ​error: (error) => setUserDataInfo({
          ​status: 'error',
          ​data: null,
          ​error
        ​})
      ​}
    );
  ​}, [user]);

  ​// you can rename these as desired:
  ​return (
    ​<FirebaseAuthUserContext.Provider value={{​
      ​get data() { return userDataInfo.data }, // for convenience
      ​dataInfo: userDataInfo,
      ​dataStatus: userDataInfo.status, // for convenience
      ​initializing,
      user
    ​}}>
      ​{children}
    ​</FirebaseAuthUserContext.Provider>
 ​ );
}
```

**Note:** You could split out the user data from this `FirebaseAuthUserContext` into another context, say `FirebaseAuthUserDataContext`, but more often than not, you'll need both anyway so you can just lump them together.

Using the above `Context` object, you'd update your `Routes` component to be just:

```js
import useAuth from './FirebaseAuthUserContext.jsx';

export default function Routes() {
  ​const userInfo = useAuth();

  if (​userInfo.initializing) return null; // hide while loading

  ​return (
    ​<NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
      ​{userInfo.user ? <TabStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    ​</NavigationContainer>
  ​);
}
```

Here is another example of using this `Context` object for something that needs to use the user's data:

```js
import FirebaseAuthUserContext from '...';

export default function CurrentUserIcon() {
  ​const userInfo = useContext(FirebaseAuthUserContext);

  switch (userInfo.dataStatus) {
    case "loaded":
      return (
        <div class="user-icon">
          <a href="/profile/settings">
            <img src={userInfo.data.profileImage} />
            <span>@{userInfo.data.username}</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    case "not-found": 
      return (
        <div class="user-icon">
          <a href="/profile/settings">
            <img src={PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_URL} />
            <span>New user</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      // unexpected status: loading/error/signed-out
      return null;
  }
}
```

If you are making use of Typescript, you can help yourself out by defining the different various different states that the context could be in:

```js
// at top of ./FirebaseAuthUserContext.jsx
import type { User } from "firebase/auth";
import type { DocumentReference, FirestoreError } from "firebase/firestore";

export interface UserData {
  ​// shape of your user's data
}

interface UserDataInfo$Error {
 ​ status: "error";
 ​ data: null;
  ​error: FirestoreError;
}
interface UserDataInfo$Loaded {
  ​status: "loaded";
  ​data: UserData;
  ​ref: DocumentReference<UserData>;
}
interface UserDataInfo$Loading {
 ​ status: "loading";
  ​data?: undefined;
}
interface UserDataInfo$NotFound {
 ​ status: "not-found";
  ​data: null;
  ​ref: DocumentReference<UserData>;
}
interface UserDataInfo$SignedOut {
 ​ status: "signed-out";
 ​ data: null;
}

type UserDataInfo =
 | UserDataInfo$Error
 | UserDataInfo$Loaded
 | UserDataInfo$Loading
 | UserDataInfo$NotFound
 ​| UserDataInfo$SignedOut;

interface LiftedUserDataInfo<T extends UserDataInfo> {
  data: T["data"];
  dataInfo: T;
  ​dataStatus: T["status"];
}

​interface FirebaseAuthUserContextType$Initializing extends LiftedUserDataInfo<UserDataInfo$Loading> {
  ​user: undefined;
  initializing: true;
}

interface FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedIn<T extends 
 ​| UserDataInfo$Error
 ​| UserDataInfo$Loaded
 ​| UserDataInfo$Loading
 ​| UserDataInfo$NotFound
> extends LiftedUserDataInfo<T> {
  ​user: User;
 ​ initializing: false;
}

interface FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedOut extends LiftedUserDataInfo<UserDataInfo$SignedOut> {
  user: null;
  initializing: false;
}

export type FirebaseAuthUserContextType =
 ​| FirebaseAuthUserContextType$Initializing
 ​| FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedIn<UserDataInfo$Error>
 | FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedIn<UserDataInfo$Loaded>
 ​| FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedIn<UserDataInfo$Loading>
 ​| FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedIn<UserDataInfo$NotFound>
 ​| FirebaseAuthUserContextType$SignedOut;

export const FirebaseAuthUserContext = createContext<FirebaseAuthUserContextType>({
  data: undefined,
  dataInfo: { status: "loading" },
  dataStatus: "loading",
  initializing: true,
  user: undefined
} as FirebaseAuthUserContextType$Initializing);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share this with me! I'm going through it now to implement it into my application! Will update!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use a splash screen then navigate to other stacks however you still can do it without splash like below

```
{user === 'loading' ? <LoadingPage /> : user ? <TabStack /> : <AuthStack />}
```

I assume that the initial user value is 'loading'