# React context with firebase snapshot on user doc

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

For some reason, when inside my function "login", my "currentUser" state always returns null.
What I'm trying to do is setting a snapshot on the user document when the user logs in.

I'm also not sure if I can save the unsubscribe function in state like this but that's a problem I didn't have the chance to have yet

My context component looks like this:

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth, db } from '../init/firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  // User firebase doc init
  const [userDoc, setUserDoc] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    data: [],
  })
  const [firebaseUnsubscriber, setFirebaseUnsubscriber] = useState(null);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  }

  function login(email, password) {
    return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(() => {
      // The problem here is that "currentUser" is always null
      const firebaseUnsubscriber = db.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        setUserDoc({
          loaded: true,
          data: doc.data(),
        })
      });
  
      setFirebaseUnsubscriber(firebaseUnsubscriber);
    })
  }

  function logout() {
    return auth.signOut().then(() => {
      firebaseUnsubscriber();
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscriber = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
      setLoading(false)
    })

    return unsubscriber
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    userDoc,
    login,
    signup,
    logout,
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of timing. When you call `setCurrentUser` or any other setter returned from a `useState()` call, you don't change the current value of the variable - you instead set the **next** value of the variable - which won't be used until React decides a rerender is needed.

Instead of making use of `currentUser` from your state in the `then` handler of  [`signInWithEmailAndPassword()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword), you should instead be using the [`UserCredential`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth#usercredential) object that is contained in the Promise.

```
function login(email, password) {
  return auth
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const firebaseUnsubscriber = db.collection("users")
        .doc(userCredential.user.uid)
        .onSnapshot((doc) => {
          setUserDoc({
            loaded: true,
            data: doc.data(),
          })
        });
  
      setFirebaseUnsubscriber(firebaseUnsubscriber);
    });
}
```

Now while the above code will function to fix your issue, there are a number of problems that remain:

- `setFirebaseUnsubscriber` is storing an unsubscriber function in the state, which would cause a rerender which would mean that the unsubscriber should be invoked, which causes a new unsubscriber to be stored, which would mean that the unsubscriber should be invoked, which causes ... (the user data portion should be in its own `useEffect`)
- Errors with retrieving the user's data are silently ignored
- A newly created user won't have any user data to be loaded (and `data` will be set to `undefined` instead of `[]` like in the initial state)
- A user who signed out doesn't have their data cleared
- Your `currentUser` state variable has a type of `User | "" | null`. Either user `User | null` (recommended when using `loading`) or `User | null | undefined`.
- The loading state of the current user isn't exposed to the context consumers
- The current code makes use of the should-be-considered-deprecated namespaced v8 Web SDK - if writing new code, you should be [using the modular v9 Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

For a somewhat complex, but robust, way of fixing these issues, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190) and its version of `FirebaseAuthUserContext`. At the time of writing, it uses the v8 SDK but I will update it to v9 in the future.