# React useState and Context Issue: Unsubscribe Functions Remain undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, react-hooks, react-context

Context:
I'm working on a Next.js application with Firebase and facing an issue with state propagation through a React context. I'm trying to update my context's state with unsubscribe functions for Firestore listeners, but these functions are persisting as undefined in the consumer components.

Problem:
The unsubscribeDocuments and unsubscribeUserReservations functions, defined in my custom hook useFirebaseAuth and updated via useState, remain undefined when consumed in my UserAccountNavigation component.

Code:

```
// AuthUserContext.tsx
"use client";
import useFirebaseAuth from "@/hooks/use-firebase-auth";
import { UserDocument, UserReservation } from "@/types/user";
import { useContext, createContext, useState } from "react";

const init = {
  uid: "",
  email: "",
  displayName: "",
  emailVerified: false,
  phoneNumber: "",
  photoURL: "",
  userDocument: {} as UserDocument,
  userReservation: [] as UserReservation[],
};

const authUserContext = createContext({
  authUser: init,
  authUserIsLoading: true,
  reloadAuthUserData: () => {},
  setUnsubscribeDocuments: (unsubscribeDocuments: () => void) => {},
  unsubscribeDocuments: () => {},
  setUnsubscribeUserReservations: (
    unsubscribeUserReservations: () => void
  ) => {},
  unsubscribeUserReservations: () => {},
});

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export function AuthUserProvider({ children }: Props) {
  const auth = useFirebaseAuth();
  const [unsubscribeDocuments, setUnsubscribeDocuments] = useState<
    () => void | null
  >(() => {});
  const [unsubscribeUserReservations, setUnsubscribeUserReservations] =
    useState<() => void | null>(() => {});

  return (
    <authUserContext.Provider
      value={{
        authUser: auth.authUser as {
          uid: string;
          email: string;
          displayName: string;
          emailVerified: boolean;
          phoneNumber: string;
          photoURL: string;
          userDocument: UserDocument;
          userReservation: UserReservation[];
        },
        authUserIsLoading: auth.authUserIsLoading,
        reloadAuthUserData: auth.reloadAuthUserData,
        setUnsubscribeDocuments,
        unsubscribeDocuments,
        setUnsubscribeUserReservations,
        unsubscribeUserReservations,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </authUserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useAuth = () => useContext(authUserContext);
//

// AuthUserProvider.tsx
export default function useFirebaseAuth() {

  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<UserInterface | null>(null);

  const [authUserIsLoading, setAuthUserIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { setUnsubscribeDocuments, setUnsubscribeUserReservations } = useAuth();

  console.log("setUnsubscribeDocuments", setUnsubscribeDocuments);
  console.log("setUnsubscribeUserReservations", setUnsubscribeUserReservations);


  const reloadAuthUserData = () => {
    if (auth.currentUser) {
      auth.currentUser.reload().then(() => {
        authStateChanged(auth.currentUser);
      });
    }
  };

  const formatAuthUser = (user: UserInterface) => ({
    uid: user.uid,
    email: user.email,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
    phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber,
    photoURL: user.photoURL,
  });

  const getUserReservations = async (user: UserInterface) => {
    const reservationsRef = collection(db, "reservations");
    const q = query(reservationsRef, where("uidUser", "==", user.uid));

    const dataUserWithReservation = user;

    const unsubscribeResa = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        dataUserWithReservation.userReservation = querySnapshot.docs.map(
          (doc) => doc.data() as UserReservation
        );
      } else {
        dataUserWithReservation.userReservation = [];
      }

      setAuthUser((prevAuthUser) => ({
        ...prevAuthUser,
        ...dataUserWithReservation,
      }));
      setAuthUserIsLoading(false);
    });
    setUnsubscribeUserReservations(() => unsubscribeResa);
  };


  const getUserDocument = async (user: UserInterface) => {
    if (auth.currentUser) {

      const documentRef = doc(db, "users", auth.currentUser.uid);


      const dataUserWithDocument = user;

      const unsubscribeDoc = onSnapshot(documentRef, async (doc) => {
        if (doc.exists()) {

          dataUserWithDocument.userDocument = doc.data() as UserDocument;
        }
        setAuthUser((prevAuthUser) => ({
          ...prevAuthUser,
          ...dataUserWithDocument,
        }));
        // setAuthUserIsLoading(false);
      });
      setUnsubscribeDocuments(() => unsubscribeDoc);
    }
  };

  //
  const authStateChanged = async (authState: UserInterface | User | null) => {

    if (!authState) {
      setAuthUser(null);
      setAuthUserIsLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    setAuthUserIsLoading(true);

    const formattedUser = formatAuthUser(authState);

    await getUserDocument(formattedUser);
    await getUserReservations(formattedUser);
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, authStateChanged);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return {
    authUser,
    authUserIsLoading,
    reloadAuthUserData,
  };
}
//

// UserAccountNavigation.tsx
const handleLogOutUser = async () => {
    console.log("unsubscribeDocuments", unsubscribeDocuments);
    console.log("unsubscribeUserReservations", unsubscribeUserReservations);

    // const { error } = await firebaseLogOutUser();
    // if (error) {
    //   toast.error(error.message);
    //   return;
    // }
    // toast.success("A bientôt !");
  };
//
```

What I've Tried:

Checked that the setter functions (setUnsubscribeDocuments, setUnsubscribeUserReservations) are called with the correct unsubscribe functions in useFirebaseAuth.
Confirmed that these setter functions are correctly passed in AuthUserProvider.
Used logs to confirm that the unsubscribe functions are defined before being passed to the context.
Ensured that the UserAccountNavigation component is a child of AuthUserProvider.
Question:
How can I resolve this issue where the unsubscribe functions remain undefined in consumer components, even after properly updating the state in the context?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! How are you intending on using `unsubscribeDocuments` and `unsubscribeUserReservations`? Depending on what you are trying to achieve, the better approach might be to refactor so you can use `useState` or `useSignal` without passing the unsubscribers around.

Comment: Linking with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69570345/3068190) that shares similar problems along with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190) that has an example of a 
`FirebaseAuthUserContext` implementation.