# How to display the current user display name in firebase using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to display the current user's name in my sidebar component in react.
I tried this so far.

```
import {auth, dataBase} from '../firebase-config.js';

function Sidebar() {
    const [firebaseUserInfo, setFirebaseUserInfo] = useState(auth.currentUser);

  return (
    <div className='sidebar-container'>
        <header>
          <p>{firebaseUserInfo.displayName}</p>
        </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

it seemed to work at first, but after stepping away, and coming back to refresh the app I get this error now.

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'displayName')
```

How can I fix this problem. and render the user's name?

edit:
as requested this is the my signIn.js that allows firebase to auth users.

this is the imports

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {auth, googleProvider, facebookProvider, twitterProvider, githubProvider} from '../firebase-config.js';
import {signInWithPopup, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
```

this the google firebase auth provider function

```
  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
      console.log(result);
      cookies.set("auth-token", result.user.refreshToken);
      setIsSignIn(true);
      }
    catch (err){
      console.error(err);
    }           
  }
```

here is the firebase-config.js file that houses all the firebase variables and commends.

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import {getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, FacebookAuthProvider, TwitterAuthProvider, GithubAuthProvider} from 'firebase/auth';
import {getFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCtiHPj2f0IB389CHZSkc0cAOCBkYf7RFw",
  authDomain: "my-chat-app-5b0ae.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "my-chat-app-5b0ae",
  storageBucket: "my-chat-app-5b0ae.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "837847743265",
  appId: "1:837847743265:web:cc6c4987efbf7fe47b5c60",
  measurementId: "G-CXEMWS349E"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const facebookProvider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
export const twitterProvider = new TwitterAuthProvider();
export const githubProvider = new GithubAuthProvider();
export const dataBase = getFirestore(app)
```

also here is a link to my current code on github
https://github.com/rsteward117/Chat-App/tree/main/src

Comment: I haven't worked with firebase much before, but this may be the case when you get the value of auth using an `async` function and aren't `await`ing it. Can you post your code that contains the logic that gets `auth` from firebsae?

Comment: sure thing, this one the auth async functions that uses google as a sign in provider. `  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try{
      const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
      //this sets a refresh token from firebase within cookie to the app so the user doesn't have to keep loging inwith google
      console.log(result);
      cookies.set("auth-token", result.user.refreshToken);
      setIsSignIn(true);
      }
    catch (err){
      console.error(err);
    }           
  }`

Comment: I may be missing something, so apologies if I am, but I can't seem to find the point of definition for `auth` in your code. Also, can you add the relevant code edited inside your original question? It helps with viewing it properly due to the formatting.

Comment: I edited it with the relevant code with a link to my github account at the end. there's also a file that configs firebase called 'firebase-config.js' in the src folder that were I imported the firebase commends, and variables , and export them through out the ret of the project.

Answer (score 2):

Per the [API reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authcurrentuser) and [the relevant documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> You can also get the currently signed-in user by using the `currentUser` property. If a user isn't signed in, `currentUser` is `null`…
>
> **Note:** `currentUser` might also be `null` because the auth object has not finished initializing. If you use an observer to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case.

When a page is reloaded, Firebase needs time to confirm that the user currently signed in is still authorized. This involves sending a request off to Firebase and then handling the response. While this is ongoing, `auth.currentUser` will be `null`.

With this in mind, your current code is partially complete as you have configured the `firebaseUserInfo` state variable but have not yet attached an event listener to update it. To listen for this change, you need to register a listener using [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged):

```
// you already have this line
const [firebaseUserInfo, setFirebaseUserInfo] = useState(auth.currentUser);

// but you missed this one
useEffect(() => onAuthStateChanged(auth, setFirebaseUserInfo), []);
```

With this extra line, the `firebaseUserInfo` object will be updated whenever it is changed by the Firebase library.

However, this still has the problem where it might be `null` for a brief moment and throw the error you are seeing. To handle this situation, you can pluck the `displayName` property from the user info object when it is present, and when it is not, use a fallback value:

```
const displayName = firebaseUserInfo?.displayName || "Loading…";

return (
    <div className='sidebar-container'>
        <header>
          <p>{displayName}</p>
        </header>
    </div>
  );
```

OR, the more concise but less readable:

```
return (
    <div className='sidebar-container'>
        <header>
          <p>{firebaseUserInfo?.displayName || "Loading…"}</p>
        </header>
    </div>
  );
```

You'll now see that your sidebar will either show the display name straight away or show "Loading…" for a moment.

---

In the long term, it would be best to implement a [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) that handles these listeners and intermediate states for you. As long as the context is higher in the component tree, it will allow you to use code like the below example to pull information about the user:

```
const { dataStatus, user, data } = useAuth();

if (dataStatus === "loading") return (<p>Loading stats…</p>);
if (!user) return (<p class="error">Error: Log in required.</p>);

return (<p>@{user.displayName} has {data.allTimeViewCount} total views on their channel.</p>);
```

An example of a `FirebaseAuthUserContext`, along with some more details, can be found in [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68871889/3068190). There are various other implementations around that you can seek out.

Answer (score 1):

When you reload the page, firebaseUserInfo is undefined or null until firebase actually authenticates your user.

try

```
firebaseUserInfo?.displayName // add ? for null check. This will prevent your app from crashing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually dont need to `useState` to get the auth details. Upadate the code to following

```
import {auth, dataBase} from '../firebase-config.js';

function Sidebar() {
   const displayName = auth?.displayName || "None provided" //if no name no error will be shown

  return (
    <div className='sidebar-container'>
        <header>
          <p>{displayName}</p>
        </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```